# virtual host `Redirect permanent` redirecting all http > https from one single vhost

Tags: server, apache2

The error I am having is:

All http domains are being forwarded to https://www.XYZ.com as a single example outlined below:

```
Current:
http://warhammer.ABC.com > https://www.XYZ.com //incorrect
http://www.EDF.com       > https://www.XYZ.com //incorrect
http://www.XYZ.com       > https://www.XYZ.com //correct

Expected:
http://warhammer.ABC.com > https://warhammer.ABC.com
http://www.EDF.com       > http://www.DEF.com
http://www.XYZ.com       > https://www.XYZ.com
```

### abc.vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName warhammer.ABC.com
    Redirect permanent / https://warhammer.ABC.com/
</VirtualHost>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName warhammer.ABC.com
    
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

    DocumentRoot /var/www/warhammer.ABC.com
    <Directory /var/www/warhammer.ABC.com>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ....
    
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

### xyz.vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.xyz.com
    Redirect permanent / https://api.xyz.com
</VirtualHost>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName api.xyz.com

        ProxyRequests on

        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:4006/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:4006/
        
        ....

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

### edf.vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/edf.com
    ServerName www.edf.com
    ServerAlias edf.com

    php_value include_path "/usr/share/php:/var/www/edf.com"
    php_value error_reporting 2047
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
    php_flag short_open_tag off

    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

    <Directory /var/www/edf.com>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Well I think what happens is you only have one valid ssl certificate (it happens to me frequently), but this site is not suitable for this kind of questions, try asking at [su]

Comment: I actually had just removed the ssl certificates. I have left the question open as in the end, resetting chrome was the answer to sorting out the redirects. Even after flushing my local DNS `(base) hutber@hutber:~$ sudo resolvectl flush-caches
(base) hutber@hutber:~$ sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches`